# How Can You Reorder And Reorganize Coordinates From A KML File With PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

According to http://assemblysys.com/php-point-in-polygon-algorithm/ I can take a group of points that form a polygon and determine whether or not a point resides inside or outside the polygon. I have also created an KML file when is being utilized by JavaScript to determine which points are inside, however my end goal would to have each marker contain an extra data set inside of a MySQL table that will store this data for later use resulting in a quicker map load time.

Looking through the KML file, each Polygon has a set of coordinates that are separated by ",0.0" which means little because according to the above document I only need the set of lats and longs. In addition, the latitudes and longitudes are in different places. Below is an example of the cordinates:

-86.1459875,39.8622513,0.0 -86.1459875,39.8555639,0.0 -86.1398077,39.8556628,0.0 -86.1398077,39.862218399999996,0.0 -86.1459875,39.8622513,0.0

Instead I want the set to look like the following:

39.8622513 -86.1459875, 39.8555639 -86.1459875, 39.8556628 -86.1398077, 39.862218399999996 -86.1398077, 39.8622513 -86.1459875

Below is a sample of my code, however I am not sure if there is an easier way of manipulating the array using PHP without the use of multiple for loops or foreach loops.

```
$kml = 'document.xml'; 
//get the total number polygons 
$numPoly = count( $kml->Document[0]->Folder);
$newArray = array(); 
$a = 1; 
$explode;
$explode['coordinates']; 
for( $i=0; $i <= $numPoly; $i++)
{
    $numPlace = count( $kml->Document[0]->Folder[$i]->Placemark); //count   the number of placemarks there are 
for($z = 0; $z <= $numPlace; $z++) 
{
    $regionName = $kml->Document[0]->Folder[$i]->Placemark[$z]->name."</br>"; //grab each placemarks name 
    //get the cordinates inside of each placemark 
    $regionCords = $kml->Document[0]->Folder[$i]->Placemark[$z]->Polygon->outerBoundaryIs->LinearRing->coordinates;
    //print_r($regionCords); print "<br/><br/>";
    foreach($regionCords as $num2 => $region)
    {
        print $a;
        $explodeCords = array_splice( explode('|', str_replace(',0.0',' |', $regionCords) ), 0, -1 ) ;

        foreach ($explodeCords as $exploded)
        {
            $exploded = explode(',', $exploded);
            $exploded1 = $exploded[0];
            $exploded2 = $exploded[1];
            $explodedString = $exploded2.$exploded1.",";
            //echo $explodedString; echo "<br/><br/>";
        }
    }
    $numCordinates =  count($explodeCords['coordinates'] ); //returns the number of [lat,long] cords in each cordinate set
    if ( !empty( $regionCords ) )
    {
        $a++;

    }
}
}
```

Please let me know if I am on the right path or if there is another way you can easily switch these two numbers using mostly array functions with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

A solution: after each foreach loop, it is best practice to remove the new array out of the loop, because if you are to add another foreach loop, unwanted effects may result such as appending a value to a new array in multiples.

After the values are removed from the foreach loop, you can always use a array_map to switch the coordinates. For a more completed example of this please see the following Github repo: https://github.com/jdmagic21/GMapParse